# Asp.Net Identity 2.0 AddToRolesAsync - Error "Email somename@somedomain.com is already taken"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I have a new application built on top of the the Identity 2.0 Samples and am having trouble with UsersAdmin/Edit. When the the application posts back to this page the line `var result = UserManager,AddToRolesAsync(string userid, string[] roles)` generates a result error stating that the email address is already taken.  "The Email somename@somedomain.com is already taken." With `result.Succeeded = false;` Here is the HttpPost Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(EditUserViewModel editUser, 
                                     params string[] selectedRole)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(editUser.Id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        // if email is unchanged don't update it.
        if (user.Email != editUser.Email) 
        { 
            user.Email = editUser.Email;
            user.EmailConfirmed = false;
        }

        var userRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);

        selectedRole = selectedRole ?? new string[] { };

        // Identity tries to update the email address here and returns an error?
        var result = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id,
                     selectedRole.Except(userRoles).ToArray<string>());

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
            return View(new EditUserViewModel()
            {
                Id = user.Id,
                MemberName = user.Name,
                Email = user.Email,
                MemberAddress = user.Address,
                RolesList = RoleManager.Roles.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Selected = userRoles.Contains(x.Name),
                    Text = x.Name,
                    Value = x.Name
                })
            });
        }
        result = await UserManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user.Id, userRoles.Except(selectedRole).ToArray<string>());

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
            return View();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something failed.");
    return View(editUser);
}
```

Here is the UserManager class (Vanilla from the Samples):

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}
```

I can see that the `ApplicationUserManager Create` Method in `IdentityConfig` is firing and that is where 'RequireUniqueEmail = true;' is set, but I do not understand why it is trying to create a new User and not just validating the existing user that `UserManager.FindByIdAsync(editUser.Id)` returns above. Here is the `ApplicationUserManager` class:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options,
        IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationIdentityDbContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
        // why is this being enforced on an existing user when the email 
        // address is not being updated but UserRoles are?
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };
        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };
        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;
        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug in here.
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("PhoneCode", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is: {0}"
        });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("EmailCode", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            Subject = "SecurityCode",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}
```

As you can see I haven't gotten as far as configuring the Two Factor Authentication. Any insight you can provide would be most helpful. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I verified that if I comment out "RequireUniqueEmail = true"  I can update the Roles on the selected user but that also disables that layer of validation at the new user creation level. Something I would rather avoid having to do.  Is the there a way to enforce this rule only when new users are created and only when existing users attempt to update their email address?

Comment: Is email used as username? does the same username already exist?

Comment: I separated email from username in M, V and C. Seems related to accounts I created with Update-Database through the console.  I have 5 accounts that are all admin accounts for different roles and they all have the same email address.  This is fine because there is no constraint on the email field in the database and handy because all service email goes to the same account.  But the UserManager keeps enforcing this policy on pre-existing user accounts when there is no change to the email address.  I need to momentarily disable that check if email has not been updated.

Comment: I've run into this same problem. Everything would work fine until we migrated the old ASP.Membership database to the new Identity framework. Turns out the user I was trying to update had another user with the same email in the AspNetUsers table. We were using usernames for our old site, but switched to emails in the new site. So setting the email to null in the database fixed the problem. Probably going to look into requiring unique emails for our app 2.0

Comment: Update: Main problem is that my application has 5 service accounts pre-populated with the same admin email address.  I see no way to trap or step into the errors that were being generated, but narrowed it down when having problems with `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` not logging `AccessFailedCounts`.  The standard `SigninStatus.Failure` was returned but in a black box way. I'm not sure why EF has to update email on this and every other change to a user in Owin but it does. I'm turning the unique check off when updating existing users in most places but in this one seems too deep to handle

Comment: I feel like that check should only be running if creating a new account or changing email on an existing account. Does anyone have any ideas on overriding the current behavior?